# BeautifulSoup: Reading Span Class Elements

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having some issues web scraping information from a particular pages span class element, using the beautifulsoup and requests addon in python. It keeps returning me blank information: "  ". Heres my code:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = requests.get('https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/ontario/toronto')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

weather_elem = soup.find('span', {'class':'wxcondition'})
weather = weather_elem
print(weather)
return weather`
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded through JavaScript so BeautifulSoup doesn't see anything. But you can simulate the Ajax with the `requests` module:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/ontario/toronto'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
place_code = soup.select_one('link[rel="alternate"]')['href'].split('=')[-1].lower()
ajax_url = 'https://weatherapi.pelmorex.com/api/v1/observation/placecode/' + place_code
data = requests.get(ajax_url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['observation']['weatherCode']['text'])
```

Prints:

```
Partly cloudy
```